# Isosceles triangle of maximum area, given the length of a median to one of its equal sides

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> Find the angle at the vertex of an isosceles triangle of maximum area, given the given length ($\ell$) of the median to one of its equal sides.

I tried to get a relation between $\ell$ and one of the equal sides, but couldn't get one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In general, the polygon of maximum area $($for a given perimeter$)$ is the regular polygon. In this case, an equilateral triangle. I believe you can take it from here. $($Also, the geometric shape of maximum area for a given perimeter is the circle, and the three-dimensional solid of maximum volume for a given surface is the sphere$)$.